# Docker container without ipv4 address

Tags: ipv4, docker

Under ubuntu 13.04 with docker 0.7.2 when I create a container via Dockerfile or interactively : the network interface generated veth**** does not have an ipv4 address but an ipv6 one.

How can I get a ipv4 address ? Is there some things I missed. Does this depends from my network configuration ?

Same behaviour on a 12.04 box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The network interface `veth…` in the host *shouldn't* have an IPv4 address. Those virtual interfaces work in pairs:

- One interface will be in the container, it will be named `eth0`, and will have an IPv4 address. For all purposes, it looks like a normal interface.
- The other half of the pair is the `veth…` interface. It will be in the host, and won't have an IPv4 address.

Those two interfaces are connected together: any packet sent on an interface will appear as being received by the other. You can imagine that they are connected by a cross-over cable, if that helps :-)

The fact that the `veth…` interface has an IPv6 address is just because when IPv6 is enabled, all interfaces receive at least a link-local address. But this address is essentially useless in that case.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation ! I just discover that the ip address is available via the 'docker inspect <containerid>' .

Comment: are you sure ? how can one interface in pair have a IP address and other don't. Even if we assume that they are connected by crossover cable how do they talk ?

Comment: @VikramSingh Think it as a router with several LAN ports, a `veth` is a LAN port of the router, and `eth0` in the container is a device connected to the router. Then you know, `veth` doesn't need to have its own ip address ah

Answer (score -1):

Restart the docker service once. This will show the ipv4 address in **docker0** link

```
sudo systemctl restart docker.service
```

Please keep in mind that the running containers will be closed down.
You can check the ip by using `ifconfig` command

Comment: Surely not. As I look here, my `veth` interfaces are all IPv6, but `docker0` is, as expected, at 172.17.0.1. Restarting isn't going to change that.